# Why [Enum].Parse has an ignoreCase parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, enums

Since an Enumeration in VB.Net cannot contains duplicated values like this:

```
Enum Test
  A
  a
End Enum
```

Then why the `[Enum].Parse` method has a StringCase parameter?

```
[Enum].Parse(GetType(Enum), Value, Ignorecase)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx

> Parse(Type, String, Boolean)

It really has any sense for me.

Which with logic developers of .NET Framework Classes has written that ignorecase flag in that method?

I think that the `[Enum].Parse` logic should be to check automatically for ignorecase value instead of passing a boolean parameter to the method because an enum cannot contains duplicates ...or it can contains?

Comment: Some people really need to calm down with their down-votes. This is a perfectly reasonable question from someone who knows VB.Net and who is puzzled by an aspect of the .NET framework.

Comment: @David Amo You are right, thank you for your comprehension.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An enum *can* contain values which differ only in case - you just can't declare them in VB. This is perfectly valid C#:

```
public enum Foo
{
    A, a;
}
```

Additionally, even if the enum *couldn't* contain values differing only in case, that wouldn't mean you'd either *always* want it to be case-sensitive or *always* want it to be case-insensitive. Your suggest that it should always be case-insensitive would be annoying for situations where you were trying to provide a case-sensitive match. It's very rarely a good idea to make case-insensitive matching the only option in an API, IMO.

Comment: oh, but then if I understanded well, an Enum in VB.NET cannot contains `A` and `a`, right?

Comment: In fact, the Paypal API web service does this - it provides a WSDL with a boolean parameter that can be `Y` or `y`, which on the .NET side generates an enum with values `Y` and `y`, and that happens even if you use VB.NET - you get invalid code generated. You have to manually amend the generated files to remove the redundant `Y` and then make sure you don't refresh your web service reference, otherwise the `y` will come back and ruin your build. I was amused by this.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: An enum *declared* in VB may not be able to contain it, but that doesn't mean VB can't *consume* such an enum.

Comment: I have a quick question if someone could answer me here, The internal Framework Enums could contains "duplicated names"? or only "3rd party" Enums? I mean if exists risk of getting a false-positive using the IgnoreCase parametter with the framework Enums.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: There's nothing to stop internal framework ones containing values which differ only by case. I doubt that any of them do, but it's feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Enum.TryParse instead:

```
Enum.TryParse(value: "SoMeValUe", ignorecase: true, result: out result)
```